# Multi User login authentication | React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an application with multi user login functionality. Now, I created the redux store for the login function. If User logged in, based on their type, it will redirect to the particular dashboard. If student user logged in, he should be able to only access student dashboard, he should not able to access other dashboards. Same applies for others. But, now, if any user logged in, they can able to access other user dashboards. How can i prevent them to use only their dashboards.

Updated With Proper Code

```
/***AppRouter***/
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import StuDashboard from '../views/ed/dashboard/Dashboard.js';
    import AdminDashboard from '../views/biz/dashboard/Dashboard.js';
    import OrgDashboard from '../views/org/dashboard/Dashboard.js';
    import SupAdDashboard from '../views/me/dashboard/Dashboard.js';
    import UserLogin from '../views/loginUser/Login.js';
    import history from '../history/history.js';
    import { PrivateRoute } from './PrivateRoute.js';
    import NotFoundPage from '../views/NotFoundPage.js';
    import Authorization from './Authorization';



    class AppRouter extends Component {
      render () {
        return(

          <BrowserRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={Landing} exact />
              <Route path="/confirmation" component={EmailCon}/>
              <PrivateRoute path="/student/dashboard" component={Authorization(StuDashboard),["Student"]}/>
              <PrivateRoute path="/admin/dashboard" component={Authorization(AdminDashboard),["Admin"}/>
              <PrivateRoute path="/org/dashboard" component={Authorization(OrgDashboard),["Org"]}/>
              <PrivateRoute path="/SuperAdmin/dashboard" component={Authorization(SupAdDashboard),["SuperAdmin"]}/>
              <Route path="/login" component={UserLogin}/>  
              <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>

        );
      }
    }

    export default AppRouter;

/***PrivateRoute***/
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('token')
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
    )} />
)

/***Authorization***/
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Authorization = (WrappedComponent, allowedRoles) =>{
   class WithAuthorization extends Component {
       render() {

     const userType = this.props.user
      if (allowedRoles.includes(userType)) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
      } else {
        return <h1>You are not allowed to view this page!</h1>
      }
    }
  }
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ user: state.login.userName, userType: state.login.userType })
return connect(mapStateToProps)(WithAuthorization);
}
export  default  Authorization;

/***Action.js***/
import axios from "axios";
import { LOGIN_PENDING, LOGIN_COMPLETED, LOGIN_ERROR, LOGOUT } from "./types";
import ApiUrl from "../../constants/ApiUrl.js";
import qs from "qs";
import history from '../../history/history.js';


const startLogin = () => {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_PENDING
  };
};

const loginComplete = data => ({
  type: LOGIN_COMPLETED,
  data
});

const loginError = err => ({
  type: LOGIN_ERROR,  
  err
});

export const loginUser = (email, password) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(startLogin());

    let headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    };

    const data = qs.stringify({
      grant_type: "password",
      username: email,
      password: password,
    });

    axios
      .post(`${ApiUrl}/Token`, data, {
        headers: headers
      })

      .then(function (resp) {

        dispatch(loginComplete(resp.data));


       localStorage.setItem("token", resp.data.access_token);
      switch (resp.data.userType) {
        case 'Admin': {
          history.push('/admin/dashboard');
          break;
        }
        case 'Student': {
          history.push('/student/dashboard');
          break;
        }
        case 'Organization': {
          history.push('/org/dashboard');
          break;
        }
        case 'SuperAdmin': {
          history.push('/SuperAdmin/dashboard');
          break;
        }
        default:
         history.push('/');
      }
      window.location.reload();
      return;


})
      .catch(err => dispatch(loginError(err)));
  };
};

export const logOut = () => {
  localStorage.clear();
  return {
    type: LOGOUT,
  };
}
```

Comment: Maybe instead of having one Private Route....create two route definitions based on the user logging in? For example create a PrivateStudent Route and a route for others...

Answer (score 3):

I added an `Authorization` HOC to cater for access control. So you just pass the component, and the allowed role to the Authorization HOC.First i assume your user has a property `userType`.  check out this [URL](https://hackernoon.com/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4).

```
  /***Authorization***/
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Authorization = (WrappedComponent, allowedRoles) => {
  class WithAuthorization extends Component {
    render() {
      const userType  = this.props.userType;
      if (allowedRoles.includes(userType)) {
        return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
      } else {
        return <h1>You are not allowed to view this page!</h1>;
      }
    }
  }
  const mapStateToProps = state => ({ user: state.login.userName, userType: state.login.userType })
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(WithAuthorization);
};
export default Authorization;
```

---

your router will then look this way

```
      <BrowserRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Landing} exact />
          <Route path="/confirmation" component={EmailCon}/>
          <PrivateRoute path="/student/dashboard" component={Authorization(StuDashboard,["Student"])}/>
          <PrivateRoute path="/admin/dashboard" component={Authorization(AdminDashboard,["Admin"])}/>
          <PrivateRoute path="/org/dashboard" component={ Authorization(OrgDashboard,["Organization"])}/>
          <PrivateRoute path="/SuperAdmin/dashboard" component={Authorization(SupAdDashboard,["SuperAdmin"])}/>
          <Route path="/login" component={UserLogin}/>  
          <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code, as per your suggestions. Still getting error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined". I have also updated my code above. Please check  @Obed

Comment: I have fixed the bug, Let me know if you would prefer a functional component instead, I can provide an answer for it too.

Comment: I have updated the code and checked on that. If you check my updated code above. I am getting userName and userType from the Store and passed in the component. After,  I login with any user type. It will show the  "you are not allowed to view this condition" condition. I don't get, where i am making mistake. Yeah, please share the functional component method, it will be useful to grow my knowledge in react. Thanks for your patience @Obed

Comment: You are getting the username into the user which i guess is just a string, so there is no `user.userType` on user(userName). I have updated the code to correct that

Comment: I updated the code. But, it still showing the same. @Obed

Comment: kindly console the state and find out what is in the state at the point of login. I think the state is empty when the `Authorization` is called. You can you create a stackblitz with that portion of your code, so I can walk you through.

Comment: I am getting the state, i checked with the redux dev tool and also checked via console. If possible can you provide an functional component for this.

Comment: There is an mistake in your code, change "const {userType} = this.props.userType" to "const userType = this.props.userType". Once, I changed this, its working.